# Accessing Outlook journal entries from C#

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, office-interop, office-automation

For the last 7 years I've been using the Journal entries feature of Outlook to generate daily engineering log entries detailing what I've been working on day-to-day. It looks like MS are 'retiring' the Journal feature in the near future and I'd like to retain my 1000+ log entries.

Ideally I would like to export all the Journal entries into a SQLite database and use it as the basis of a new engineering log tool.

Reviewing the available MSDN documentation I was only able to find scant details on programmatically accessing Outlook data. I did identify a number of pay for/open source NuGet packages for accessing Outlook data, but none of them seemed to cover Journal entries.

Has anyone recommend a NuGet package/GitHub project which would handle this, or even a code snippet highlighting accessing Outlook Journal entries ?

Answer (score 1):

[JournalItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.journalitem) object can be accessed using Outlook Object Model just fine. Open the default Journal folder using `Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderJournal)`, loop through all items in that folder (cast them to [JournalItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.journalitem)).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getdefaultfolder) method to get the `Journal` folder which contains corresponding items. Just pass the `olFolderJournal` value. For example, the following VBA macro which can be run on Outlook shows how to get the Journal folder:

```
Public Sub OpenJournalEntry()
  Dim JournalFolder As Folder
  Dim Item As Object
  Set JournalFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderJournal)
  Set Items = JournalFolder.Items
  Set Item = Items.Item(1)
  Item.Display
End Sub
```